# root of unity in a local field

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Let $K$ be a local field with residue field of cardinality $q$ that contains the $n$-th roots of unity (for some $n\in\mathbb N^*$). Does $n$ divide $q-1$?

If not, is there a relation between $n$ and $q$?

Thanks in  advance

Comment: Try $\mathbf Q_2$ and $n=2$. If you take $n$ to be relatively prime to $q$ then your guess is right.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the general case, there is no obvious relation?

Comment: The prime-to-$p$ part of $n$ divides $q-1$, where $p$ is the residue field characteristic.

Comment: Thank you for your help. Do you know some good references talking about that?

Comment: Have you ever read a book on local fields?

Comment: Yes, Schikhov and Robert. But there is nothing about that in these book

Comment: Try Serre's "Local Fields." There is a section in it  on cyclotomic extensions of $\mathbf Q_p$. Or better yet, just try working this stuff out for yourself. It is an instructive experience.

Comment: The barebones fact is that if the $p^m$ roots of unity are there, then the ramification index (over $\Bbb Q_p$) must be divisible by $(p-1)p^{m-1}$. The converse is by no means true. I find knowledge of the Newton Polygon most useful here.